# changing the url in the extended class

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to learn Java. I extend from a class and each extended page goes to its own url. How can I change the "url" as variable?
Here is my code :

```
public class BaseTest {
    
        
        public static String baseUrl;
        public void setUp() throws InterruptedException  {
           //there is some code for setup.
            driver.get("https://www.hurriyet.com.tr/");
            
        }
 other page is extends like this:

public class sample1page extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void method() throws InterruptedException {
        
        //here ı need to change url
    }
public class sample2page extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void edituseracco() throws InterruptedException {
        
        //here ı need to change url
    }
```

Comment: by setting the value? there is no need for baseUrl to be static, it makes no sense to be static. also: don't call methods on non-existing variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a static variable, single copy of variable is created and shared among all objects at the class level.

So, parent class and all child classes share the same variable. Now one change reflects everywhere.

```
public void method() throws InterruptedException {
  BaseTest.baseUrl = "http://hollo.com";
}
```

Moreover, if you want to declare the same (name and type) variable, inside every child class, you can avoid the above situation.

```
class Sample1page extends BaseTest {
    public static String baseUrl;
    @Test
    public void method() throws InterruptedException {

        baseUrl = "http://example.com";
    }
}
```

But, this time similar child classes shares the same variable if you declare the variable static.

So, if you want own baseUrl for every objects, then you should not declare it as static.

```
class Sample1page extends BaseTest {
    public String baseUrl;
    @Test
    public void method() throws InterruptedException {

        baseUrl = "http://example.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: baseUrl should be declared as private, not public. Also, it should be declared in the parent class (BaseTest) not the child classes individually

Comment: Yes, you are correct. we should declare them private. Thanks :)